# Slick carousel kenwheeler- making a div visible only for slide 2 and hide for others

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slide, slick.js

I am trying to make a div filled with other images which is place just under the carousel to only show for the slide 2 of the slick slide carousel from kenwheeler and hide for others, but i dont know how to target that in JS.

please can anyone help?

```
            <div class="center">
         <div id="day1"><img width="460px" height="460px" src="1_Promotion_460px_new.gif"/>
          <p>DAY 1</p></div>
          <div id="day2"><img width="460px" height="460px" src="2_Promotion_460px_new.gif"/>
          <p>DAY 2</p></div>
          <div id="day3"><img width="460px" height="460px" src="3_Promotion_460px_new.gif"/>
          <p>DAY 3</p></div>
            <div id="day4"><img width="460px" height="460px" src="4_Promotion_460px_new.gif"/>
          <p>DAY 4</p></div>
          <div id="day5"><img width="460px" height="460px" src="5_Promotion_460px_new.gif"/>
          <p>DAY 5</p></div>
          <div id="day6"><img width="460px" height="460px" src="6_Promotion_460px_new.gif"/>
          <p>DAY 6</p></div>
            <div id="day7"><img width="460px" height="460px" src="7_Promotion_460px_new.gif"/>
          <p>DAY 7</p></div>
            <div id="day8"><img width="460px" height="460px" src="8_Promotion_460px_new.gif"/>
          <p>DAY 8</p></div>
          </div>

            <div id="product-container">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="carousel_03.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img src="carousel_03.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img src="carousel_03.jpg"/></li>
                </ul>


            </div>
```

Comment: Is there a hook for which slide is active in the carousel? Does it place an active class on the item perhaps? You could use jquery to get that active class from the list, and when it exists on the item you want, then show your div.

Comment: basically when the slide is on center (which is when i want the other div to appear only) the class ''slick-slide' will have class added to it and it will have become 'slick-slide slick-current slick-center'. so i had this jquery created but it doesnt work, it shows it for all slides instead of just one. if($('#day2').hasClass('slick-slide slick-current slick-center')){
$('.product-container').css('display','block');
}
else {
 $('.product-container').css('display','none');

}

Comment: 1) Did you try a `console.log()` in the `hasClass` check? 2) You can simplify the classes you're looking up to something like `slick-current` only, probably. 3) Where did you put that check in your app? Specifically, is it in a document ready handler? Is it off on its own?

Comment: I tried both using the document ready and also not having anything and i have placed it on top of my page. i dont know how to use the console.log sorry, i basically want to do what this website has done, for each slide different products are showing but on mine some slides will not have the products. https://www.hobbs.co.uk/aw15-lookbook#slide-4

Comment: Post the code where your jquery exists please. Everything surrounding it, because placing it at the top of the page could be incorrect if you're not doing it correctly.

Comment: sure its the same code i have in the comments above and its places before my css on the same html page. the carousel jquery was on the bottom, i have brought it to the top below my jquery code and still doesn't work. i have also tried changing the id to class and then use this code: if($('.slick-slide').hasClass('day3')){
$('#product-container').show();
}
else {
 $('#product-container').hide();

}

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function to the beforeChange event which is part of the slick slider API:

```
$('.your-sliders-class').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  if (nextSlide == 1) {
    $('#product-container').show();
  } else {
    $('#product-container').hide();
  }
});
```

Slides index start from 0, so the second slide will be index 1.
Dont forget to replace the "your-sliders-class" with your slider's class...